# VSCode Connecting to cPanel Repo

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, cpanel

I've created a Git Repo on BitBucket, and I successfully cloned it into my server using cPanels GIT Version Control page.  So now my website is displaying on my server.

What I want to do now, is directly connect to that Repo (the one on cPanel) using VSCode.  I thought there might be a way for cPanel to automatically pull changes from BitBucket - But  I can't see how to do this? So I thought the best way to would be to update the code using GIT from VSCode connecting directly to my cPanel server.

However when I do this, I get the following error:

`Host key verification failed.`.

I took the key that I used to connect to BitBucket, and put it in my ~//.shh file on my Windows 10 machine.  In VSCode I then go to a new window and click the 'Clone Repo' and put the `ssh://` line given to me in cPanel's GIT Version Control window for this repo. It looks like this:

`ssh://<user>@<domain>.net:2020/DATA/<user>/subdomains/system/labs`

VSCode then asks for a folder to put the repo into, and I get the error above, Host Verification failed.

How can I connect to this repo? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+Host+key+verification+failed

Comment: `ssh-keyscan <domain>.net -p 2020 >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts`

Comment: "*I took the key that I used to connect to BitBucket…*" This is your **user** key. The error message is about **host key**.